# Custom view inner interface throwing exception

Tags: android, exception, interface, fragment

I have a custom view as below with an inner interface to handle the button click.

```
  public class SavedContentCardView extends RelativeLayout {

        SavedItem[] mItems;
        TextView mHeader;
        Button mMoreButton;
        TextView mEmptyView;
        LinearLayout mContainer;
        OnMoreButtonClickListener mListener;

        public SavedContentCardView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initialize(context, null, 0);

        }

        public SavedContentCardView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
            super(context, set, 0);
            initialize(context, null, 0);
        }

        public SavedContentCardView(Context context, AttributeSet set, int defStyle) {
            super(context, set, defStyle);
            initialize(context, null, 0);
        }

        private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet set, int deftStyle) {
            inflate(context, R.layout.saved_content_card_layout, this);
            mHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
            mMoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
            mEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
            mContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
            mMoreButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onMoreClicked();
                }
            });
    }

        public void loadItems(List<SavedItem> items) {

            if (items == null || items.size() == 0) {
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mContainer.setVisibility(GONE);
                mHeader.setVisibility(GONE);
                mMoreButton.setVisibility(GONE);

            } else {
                for (SavedItem item : items) {
                    SavedContentRowView card = new SavedContentRowView(item, mContainer.getContext());

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);

                    mContainer.addView(card, mContainer.getChildCount(), params);
                }
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(GONE);
                mContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mHeader.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mMoreButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        public OnMoreButtonClickListener getMoreClickListener() {
            return mListener;
        }

        public void setMoreClickListener(
                OnMoreButtonClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public  interface OnMoreButtonClickListener {
            void onMoreClicked();
        }

    }
```

implementing in fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment<SavedContentPresenter> implements SavedContentView,SavedContentCardView.OnMoreButtonClickListener{

    @InjectView(R.id.savedContentCard) SavedContentCardView savedContentCard;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home, null);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        searchSrcText.setFocusable(false);
        searchSrcText.setSelected(false);
        savedContentCard.setMoreClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoreClicked() {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

while trying to implement the OnMoreButtonClickListener in a activity or fragment , I am getting the following exception

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fragments.HomeFragment
```

Comment: can you double check the package of your activity ? did you declared in the manifest ?

Comment: yup  , I have a up and running application. I get  the exception when I implement the inner fragment in the activity

Comment: The code you posted is not related to problem you facing. There's no reference to `MainActivity` anywhere.

Comment: Also you should get familiar with [Java coding convention][1], especially packages, classes and methods and then update your code to match, otherwise it's bit painful to look at your code.

Comment: OnMoreButtonClickListener is not initialized I think

Comment: just implementing the interface throws the exception

Comment: could you copy the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

May I kindly ask please, where did you initialize you listener ? 
did you really initialized it ? what is the value of mListener ?

```
          mMoreButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onMoreClicked();
            }
        });
```

Comment: ok, thx. where this V came from ? can you expand this -> part please ?